# magento associate product grid on custom tab

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I created a menu on admin panel and created two tabs under it.
1. product
2. information

I want a product grid on product tab similar to CATALOG->MANAGE PRODUCTS grid.

how to implement this can anyone tell me.

Comment: like the following tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

Comment: No that tutorial does not resolve my problem I already read that tutorial

Comment: I found a similar question that is getting same as I am getting can you have a look at this.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149892/magento-admin-tab-with-product-grid-grid-serializer-error/149900